# pointer array question in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, multidimensional-array

I realize theres a lot of array and pointer questions, but I had one thats extremely specific... Its actually from a test I took in class awhile ago and I'm still having trouble with it.

The question is - Write out a complete declaration for
A variable named pmatrix that is a pointer to an array of 8 arrays of 10 pointers to integers

so far I'm thinking something like
int*pmatrix[8][10] ,

more concerned with a good explanation than just an answer.
thanks!

Comment: http://cdecl.org is your friend.

Comment: @Oli Thanks for the link - very cool!

Answer (score 4):

A variable named pmatrix that is a pointer:

```
*pmatrix
```

to an array of 8

```
(*pmatrix)[8]
```

arrays of 10

```
(*pmatrix)[8][10]
```

pointers to integers:

```
int *(*pmatrix)[8][10]
```

Substituting into [cdecl](http://cdecl.ridiculousfish.com/?q=int+%2a%28%2apmatrix%29%5B8%5D%5B10%5D), we are told the following:

> declare pmatrix as pointer to array 8 of array 10 of pointer to int

which is where we started!

Answer (score 1):

```
int*pmatrix[8][10]
```

There's an issue of precedence: `[]` has a higher precedence
than '*', so that is an array[8] of array[10] of pointer to
`int`.  You need to add parentheses to override the precedence:

```
int (*pmatrix)[8][10]
```

(More parentheses are possible.  I'm not sure that

```
int (((*pmatrix)[8])[10]);
```

would be an improvement, however:-).)

Comment: All correct, except that it needs to be arrays of *pointers-to-`int`*, not just `int`.

Comment: Oops.  But the basic principle holds: type specification behave more or less like expressions, and you (sometimes) need parentheses to enforce precedence.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question would be

```
int* (*pmatrix)[8][10];
```

Remember though, arrays are just pointers to the first element of the array, so an array is a pointer and a pointer is an array (sometimes of just one element).

Note though, that beneath this array is really just a single-dimensional array of 80 elements. If you do an index like this:

```
int pmatrix[8][10];
pmatrix[3][5];
```

The compiler treats that as if you did:

```
*(pmatrix + (3 * 10) + 5);
```

because the index `[3][5]` accesses the **5th** element (+ 5) of the **3rd** subarray (3 * 10 (10 being the size of each sub array)).

Comment: -1: No, that's not the same.  A pointer to an array is not the same as an array.

Comment: @Oli I never said a pointer to an array is the same as an array, I said the name of an array is just a pointer to the first element of the array. Please remove your downvote.

Comment: @Seth: You basically did, when you said that `int *pmatrix[8][10]` is the right answer.  It's not the right answer.  The right answer is `int *(*pmatrix)[8][10]`.

Comment: @Oli oh, I see what you mean, I had misread the question, my eyes skipped over _a pointer to an array_ in the original question. I'll amend my answer.

Comment: @Seth: Ok, good!  But please also remove the stuff about "arrays are just pointers...", because it's all incorrect (see e.g. http://c-faq.com/aryptr/index.html).

Comment: @Oli when I run this code: `int blah[5] = {0}; cout << hex << blah << ' ' << &(blah[0]) << endl;` it prints the same number. This makes me think that the name `blah` is simply a pointer to its first element, despite what that link says, but perhaps I just don't understand it.

Comment: @Seth: Try adding the following to your example:  `int (*a)[5] = &blah; int *b = blah; cout << (a+1) << ' ' << (b+1) << endl;`.

Comment: I also disagree with the article when it says "Different code is emitted for a[x] and p[x]". If `a` is an array then the address of a is the address of the first element. `x` is added to that address and the value is fetched from that location. `p[x]` is the same way.

Comment: @Oli in your example, the compiler adds more than `sizeof(int)` because of pointer arithmetic. The operative word in my post was _underneath_. The reason why `a + 1` is different than `b + 1` in your example is that to the compiler, `sizeof(int[5])` is different than `sizeof(int)` so the compiler generates code to add 20 to the address when you say `+1`, not 4. My post applies to what's happening under the hood.

Comment: @Seth: The article is correct.  For `a[x]`, the machine code will be something like `LOAD &x, r0; ADD &a, r0; LOAD r0, r2`.  For `p[x]`, it will be something like `LOAD &x, r0; LOAD &p, r1; ADD r1, r0; LOAD r0, r2`.

Comment: "arrays are just pointers to the first element of the array" what utter nonsense

Comment: @Tomalak the name of an array stores the address of the first element. `a[0]` is the same as `*a` because `a` stores is the address of `a[0]`.

Comment: @Seth: `a` (in `int a[5]`) is no more a pointer than `b` is in `int b;`.

Comment: @Oli You've been saying that but I don't see a reason to believe it; all experiments indicate otherwise. Do you mean that the compiler treats compile-time arrays specially? I agree with you if you do, but I haven't been talking about what the compiler thinks or how it treats things.

Comment: @Seth: I've demonstrated that it's not true "above the hood" (the semantics are different), and I've demonstrated that it's not true "under the hood" (the implementations are different).  You can keep on repeating the falsehood if you like, but it will still be false!

Comment: @Oli Where did you demonstrate it? I must have missed it.

Comment: @Seth: Take a class in type theory. Oli said it best; you might also claim that in `int b;`, all `b` does is store an address to a block of memory containing a number. Of course, in reality, you never claim this. Meanwhile, don't be misled by syntax and the ease with which one may obtain a pointer-to-the-first-element-of-an-array from an array itself.

Comment: @Seth: The C++ type system is an an application of type theory. You can't just throw away all the rules of programming because you're "not discussing theory".

Comment: If you examine an application running, you will see that when an `int` is moved into a register that contains the value `1`, the register contains the value `1`. If you move an array into a register whose first value is `1`, you'll see the address of the first element, not the first element itself.

Comment: @Seth: The pointer-arithmetic discrepancy was one demo.  Another would be the fact that you can't assign to an array.  Another would be the fact that you can't pass an array into a function.  Another would be that you cannot convert an `int [5][5]` to an `int **`.

Comment: @Seth: I've already pointed the difference in machine code.  It exists, and it's important.

Comment: @Oli an `int[5][5]` is underneath (there's that word again) really just a `int[25]`, and you can convert an `int[5][5]` to an `int*`, not `int**`, since an `int*` is really what an `int[5][5]` is.

Comment: @Seth: Precisely.  If arrays and pointers were indeed interchangeable as you claim, then you would be able to convert to `int **`.  And no, an `int [5][5]` is *not* an `int *`, neither in terms of semantics (have you tried to convert one into the other?), nor in terms of implementation.

Comment: @Oli it's because C++ doesn't really have multidimensional arrays. It's a one-dimensional array, not a two-. And yes, I just tried `int a[5][5]; int* p = (int*)a;` in a compiler and it worked as expected.

Comment: @Seth: Yes precisely, you had to force the conversion, because otherwise the compiler would complain that they're not the same.  And yes, C++ does have multidimensional arrays.  How else would you expect them to be stored, other than how an `int [5][5]` is stored?

Comment: @Oli I would expect a multidimensional array to be stored as an array of arrays. So by your definition, given an array, it could be either a multidimensional array or a one-dimensional array? Weird.

Comment: @Seth: And how would an array of arrays be stored (i.e. represented in memory), other than how C/C++ stores it?  And no, "my definition" doesn't say that!  No more so than it says that a `float` could be an `int32_t` because they're both 4 bytes in memory

Comment: @Seth: Yes, well that would be an array of pointers, not an array of arrays.  Which, as I've been arguing, is the whole point!  (no pun intended)

Comment: @Oli alright, well as we disagree, it's time to retire this argument with dignity. Thanks.

Comment: @Seth: Ok.  But you'd do well to heed the FAQ, because phrases such as "arrays are pointers" are guaranteed to get your answers downvoted on SO!

Comment: @Oli I will continue under persecution! :) Also wow, this comment thread has gotten more than two screens tall.

Comment: @Seth: Yeah, it's a long and complicated discussion isn't it.  But that's because the implications are subtle, and most people have trouble accepting them at first (because the C syntax often masks them).

Comment: @Oli, I'm really sorry, I thought I was done but I have one more question. What is `int* a = new int[5];`? Would you classify it as a pointer to an array or an array, or something else? Thanks for your patience.

Comment: @Seth: It's a pointer, both semantically and under-the-hood.  Casually, we might say that it's "a pointer to an array", or even just "an array", but technically that's incorrect.  The C/C++ standards are clear that an array is something like `int a[5]`, and that the result of `new` (and `malloc`) is simply a pointer to "allocated space".

Comment: @Seth: Actually, in the case of `new`, I got that wrong.  The standard says that it *does* indeed create an array, but it also explicitly says that it returns a *pointer* to the first element.

Comment: @Oli so you would classify it as an hybrid, being both an array and a pointer to the first element? Or does it create an array, but you don't get the actual array, all you get is a pointer to the first element?

Comment: @Seth: The latter; the only way you can access it is via a pointer-to-first-element (under the hood, the compiler will generate machine-code equivalent to my pointer example further up).

Answer (score 0):

```
int** pmatrix = new int*[8]; // Array of 8 pointers to arrays
for(int i = 0; i < 8; ++i) pmatrix[i] = new int[10]; // Create each array
```